# Query to find how many purchases were made this year, For each Artist

Tags: mysql, database

I need to list the Artist's Id_no, last name (lname) and how any purchases have been made on their releases this year. The only information about the purchases is different purchase dates.

My code so far :

```
SELECT id_no, lname, purchasedate AS num_ops
FROM Artist JOIN Sales ON Artist.id_no = Sales.artist
WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR) <= purchasedate
```

However this only returns the Id_no's who have made sales, and I need all even if it is 0. On `distrinctl name`, and `num_ops` is a date of their first `purchasedate`. I need to alter this code to list how many purchases they have been involved in within this year. I've tried using `COUNT(purchasedate)` however this just returns one row. I wish the returning table to return:

1st Column: The Artist's ID Number
2nd Column: The Aritist's Last Name
3rd Column: The number of people who have purchased their CD's (which is a count of purchasedate)

I am struggling with the 3rd column majorly, and any help would be greatly appriciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need:

- a *left* join
- to move the date condition into the `ON` clause of the JOIN
- use the `count(*)` aggregating function

Like this:

```
SELECT id_no, lname, count(purchasedate) as num_ops
FROM Artist
LEFT JOIN Sales ON Artist.id_no = Sales.artist
    AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR) <= purchasedate
GROUP BY id_no, lname
```

- The `LEFT JOIN` will ensure a row is returned for every artist even if there are no sales
- By moving the date condition into the join that will still return a row for every artist even if there's no sale for the year. If the condition is left in the `WHERE` clause, that would filter out artists that didn't make sales in the last year.

A key point here is that the join condition may contain conditions unrelated to the keys involved - that's how you get *conditional* joins, which is what you want here to make the left join still function correctly

Comment: This gives one to num_ops, even if there has been no sales, but does show all artist's

Comment: I got it, just needed to changed count(*) too count(purchasedate)